# Update Nuxt store on server side without using fetch(deprecated)

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Is there a way to update store on server side without using fetch() method.
Based on the Nuxt documentation fetch is already deprecated and I don't want to use deprecated functionality.

I am trying to use asyncData() but wasn't working when I am trying to update the store state.

Comment: `nuxtServerInit`

Comment: Ifaruki thank you. I think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: it fires after every page refresh, and only works server side, so yea

Answer (score 1):

You can call `store` methods directly from `asyncData` and update your store.

```
async asyncData ({ store }) {
  const payload = 'your payload';

  store.dispatch('yourActionName', payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. First I fetch data from API then push the data to the store.

```
  async asyncData(context) {
     const cookies = new Cookies(context.req.headers.cookie)
     const access_token = cookies.get('access_token')
     const response = await context.$axios
        .$get('/user/details/username/' + context.params.username, {
           headers: {
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
           }
     })
     context.store.dispatch('user/user/getUserByUsername', response)
     return {
        user: response
     }
  }
```